# How to get Collection of Reservations inside one select using laravel query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Having the Following Code and i want to select all reservations according to units

```
$unitsQuery = DB::table('units as u')
        ->leftJoin('reservations as r', function ($join) use($fromDate,$toDate) {
            $join->on('u.id', '=', 'r.unit_id')
                ->where('r.team_id', auth()->user()->current_team_id)
                ->where('r.date_in ', '>=' , $fromDate)
                ->where('r.date_out ', '<=' , $toDate)
                ->whereNull('r.checked_out')
                ->whereNull('r.deleted_at')
                ->where('date_out', '!=', $fromDate)
                ->where('r.status' , '!=' , 'canceled')
                ->leftJoin('customer as c','r.customer_id' , '=' ,'c.id')
                ->leftJoin('wallets as w', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('r.id', '=', 'w.holder_id')
                        ->where('w.holder_type' , 'App\Reservation');
                });
        })
        ->select('u.id as uid',
            'u.name as uname',
            'u.team_id as utid',
            'u.unit_number as unum',
            'u.status as ustatus',
            'u.sunday_day_price as sunday_price',
            'u.monday_day_price as monday_price',
            'u.tuesday_day_price as tuesday_price',
            'u.wednesday_day_price as wednesday_price',
            'u.thursday_day_price as thursday_price',
            'u.friday_day_price as friday_price',
            'u.saturday_day_price as saturday_price',
            'u.month_price as month_price',

       
        )
        ->where('u.team_id' , auth()->user()->current_team_id)
        ->where('u.enabled' , 1)
        ->whereNull('u.deleted_at')
        ->orderBy('u.unit_number' , 'asc')
        ->groupBy(['u.id'])
        ->get();
```

What am trying to achieve is to get all my rooms as well as all reservations under this room according to $fromDate and $toDate how to achieve this in one select to have something like this

```
   {
      "u.id":1,
      "reservations":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "price":200
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "price":500
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "u.id":2,
      "reservations":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "price":150
         },
         {
            "id":4,
            "price":150
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I do not understand, what the specific problem is, or do you just want us to solve your problem?

Comment: @mrhn the specific problem is that i want to avoid iterating through each unit i have to fetch it's reservations but i want to make it in one select query so is that applicable or not !

Comment: Do you use Eloquent models?

Comment: @mrhn yeah sure but i want to make it through the query builder ( like SQL ) to avoid un-expected n+1 problems

Comment: Both eloquent and Db are query builders :P there is an answer, but use Query builder for filtering and eloquent for fetching reservations. I worked on multiple saas products and that is a fairly standard aproach.

Comment: @mrhn is what am trying to achieve ( the example response i provided in the question ) applicable to be done or should i think in different way ?

Comment: It is applicable, later today will write an answer, but it is going to be with Eloquent models as that is the easiest.

Comment: @mrhn thanks i will give it a try as you recommend

Comment: Did my answer help your problem? else im glad to help debug further

Comment: @mrhn actually yeah but in my case the logic is different a little bit cause we added a period what are those reservations per month ( ex Aug from 01-8 to 31-8 my goal at the end was to draw a time table alongside with reservations so i had to fetch days in the month were 2 iterations found units & days in our period then fetching reservations according to unit and day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Unit as an eloquent model, perform your normal query. You can use with to load the relationships and will therefor be transformed if you return these units in an API controller. Basically your logic but done eloquent style, probably can be some SQL naming there can be wrong, but the basic idea is there.

```
$units = Unit::query()
    ->leftJoin('reservations as r', function ($join) use($fromDate,$toDate) {
        $join->on('units.id', '=', 'r.unit_id')
            ->where('r.team_id', auth()->user()->current_team_id)
            ->where('r.date_in ', '>=' , $fromDate)
            ->where('r.date_out ', '<=' , $toDate)
            ->whereNull('r.checked_out')
            ->whereNull('r.deleted_at')
            ->where('date_out', '!=', $fromDate)
            ->where('r.status' , '!=' , 'canceled')
            ->leftJoin('customer as c','r.customer_id' , '=' ,'c.id')
            ->leftJoin('wallets as w', function ($join) {
                $join->on('r.id', '=', 'w.holder_id')
                    ->where('w.holder_type' , 'App\Reservation');
            });
    })
    ->select(
        'units.id as uid',
        'units.name as uname',
        'units.team_id as utid',
        'units.unit_number as unum',
        'units.status as ustatus',
        'units.sunday_day_price as sunday_price',
        'units.monday_day_price as monday_price',
        'units.tuesday_day_price as tuesday_price',
        'units.wednesday_day_price as wednesday_price',
        'units.thursday_day_price as thursday_price',
        'units.friday_day_price as friday_price',
        'units.saturday_day_price as saturday_price',
        'units.month_price as month_price',
    )
    ->where('units.team_id' , auth()->user()->current_team_id)
    ->where('units.enabled' , 1)
    ->whereNull('units.deleted_at')
    ->orderBy('units.unit_number' , 'asc')
    ->groupBy(['units.id'])
    ->with('reservations')
    ->get();

return $units;
```